# why this built-in kernel module's init function won't be called on startup?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module, elf

I'm using Linux on an MMU-less ARM platform, so normal ELF files won't work and I should use FDPIC_ELF executable. but my kernel couldn't execute fdpic executables (error -8 (ENOEXEC)).

I have ecided to put some `printk()` calls in *binfmt_elf_fdpic.c* `->init()` function to trace it. but it won't work.

```c
static int __init init_elf_fdpic_binfmt(void)
{
    printk("  Mahyar: elf_fdpic: init started\n"); // delete me later!
    register_binfmt(&elf_fdpic_format);
    printk("  Mahyar: elf_fdpic: init finished\n"); // delete me later!
    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_elf_fdpic_binfmt(void)
{
    unregister_binfmt(&elf_fdpic_format);
}

core_initcall(init_elf_fdpic_binfmt);
module_exit(exit_elf_fdpic_binfmt);
```

****[For seeing the complete code on github click here!](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/binfmt_elf_fdpic.c)****

I've enabled the fdpic ELF support in menuconfig->executable-formats as built-in feature (not a kernel module). Also my kernel log level is 15 (the highest level (should print everything)).

When I change something in *binfmt_elf_fdpic.c* file, and run the `make` command, it compile that file again. so it means this file should work.
but why it won't load into kernel while startup?

Comment: Function existing isn't enough. There should probably be `module_init` or something similar there (maybe there is, but you haven't shown enough code, so I'm guessing). You're also missing the log level with `printk`

Comment: there is `core_initcall` and now I've added it to this post. but the log level as I mentioned in my question, is the highest (15). I've also added a link to this complete file on github. thanks for helping!

Comment: It's not the 15 I'm talking about. Check any usage of printk, and the KERN_ macro. Printks should show up in logs, so this is a bit odd. Do they work for other code?

Comment: Idk, but when I set log level to 15, I can see a very long log on boot (but not my printk messages) . Should I use Kdebug function instead?

Comment: @domen I also tested it with kdebug but again it didn't worked.

Comment: E.g. `KERN_INFO`. It might make sense to reduce log level, and use `KERN_ALERT` yourself, so your prints don't get lost in the flood of others.

Comment: @domen thank you so much! I used KERN_ALERT and now I can see my printed texts on startup log!